# Drawing signal with a lot of samples

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I need to display a set of signals. Each signal is defined by millions of samples. Just processing the collection (for converting samples to points according to bitmap size) of samples takes a significant amount of time (especially during scrolling).

So I implemented some kind of downsampling. I just skip some points: take every 2nd, every 3rd, every 50th point depending on signal characteristics. It increases speed very much but significantly distorts signal form.

Are there any smarter approaches?

Comment: You've explained some and told some, but we still have no idea what those signals are and what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Just a note: if you are talking about *millions* of datapoints, signal presumably real-time visualization, *do not use .NET*. There are a plenty of good libraries for Python, for example.

Comment: See this other question: [Charting massive amounts of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817960/charting-massive-amounts-of-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had a similar issue in a recent application. Our visualization (a simple line graph) became too cluttered when zoomed out to see the full extent of the data (about 7 days of samples with a sample taken every 6 seconds more or less), so down-sampling was actually the way to go. If we didn't do that, zooming out wouldn't have much meaning, as all you would see was just a big blob of lines smeared out over the screen.

It all depends on how you are going to implement the down-sampling. There's two (simple) approaches: down-sample at the moment you get your sample or down-sample at display time.
What really gives a huge performance boost in both of these cases is the proper selection of your data-sources.

Let's say you have 7 million samples, and your viewing window is just interested in the last million points. If your implementation depends on an IEnumerable, this means that the IEnumerable will have to MoveNext 6 million times before actually starting. However, if you're using something which is optimized for random reads (a List comes to mind), you can implement your own enumerator for that, more or less like this:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(int start, int count, int skip)
{
    // assume we have a field in the class which contains the data as a List<T>, named _data
    for(int i = start;i<count && i < _data.Count;i+=skip)
    {
        yield return _data[i];
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a very naive implementation, but you can do whatever you want within the for-loop (use an algorithm based on the surrounding samples to average?). However, this approach will make usually smooth out any extreme spikes in your signal, so be wary of that.

Another approach would be to create some generalized versions of your dataset for different ranges, which update itself whenever you receive a new signal. You usually don't need to update the complete dataset; just updating the end of your set is probably good enough. This allows you do do a bit more advanced processing of your data, but it will cost more memory. You will have to cache the distinct 'layers' of detail in your application.

However, reading your (short) explanation, I think a display-time optimization might be good enough. You will always get a distortion in your signal if you generalize. You always lose data. It's up to the algorithm you choose on how this distortion will occur, and how noticeable it will be.

Answer (score 1):

You need a better sampling algorithm, also you can employ parallel processing features of c#. Refer to [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx)